# iOS >> UITextView >> Automatically "Jump" to the Last Line

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView that automatically prints some sort of log whenever the user is doing something in a certain view.

I wish to have it "jump" to the last line whenever a new line is added. Currently it just stays where it is and you have to manually scroll down if you wish to see the new lines.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but according to the documentation there's `- (void) scrollRangeToVisible:(NSRange)range`.

So you would do this:

```
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([myTextView.text length], 0)]
```

Basically, we pass the past-the-bound range of your text.

Comment: Please let me know why it does not work when the last range is an empty line. The cursor is just halved in my case, as in out of the content area.

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. As such you can query its `contentsSize` and call `setContentOffset:animated:` to move to the new text.

Answer (score 1):

haven't tried this, it should work

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, theTextView.contentSize.height - theTextView.bounds.size.height);
[theTextView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```